# window is not equal to <UIAlertController and window is not equal to <SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, segue

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {        
        if (segue.identifier == "login")
        {        
          if (adLabel.text == "" || syerLabel.text == "")
          {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Uyarı!", message: "Boş Alan Bırakmayınız", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Tamam", style: .default) { action in

            })            
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
          }            
        else
            {
            let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
            next.loadView()
            let nesne:MenuViewController = next.rearViewController as! MenuViewController
            nesne.adlabel = adLabel.text!
            nesne.syerLabel=syerLabel.text!

                self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        }    
    }
```

Getting this error

```
<UIView: 0x7fb2bd719f30; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x608000237820>>'s window is not equal to <UIAlertController: 0x7fb2bd7218e0>'s view's window!    
////    
<UIView: 0x7fb2bd719f30; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x608000237820>>'s window is not equal to <SWRevealViewController: 0x7fb2be882e00>'s view's window!`
```

i used to **dispactquequ.main.async** but i got this error **whose view is not in the window hierarchy!**
Thank you

Comment: Show your storyboard structure and performSegue method.

Comment: i dont use perfomsegue func ,should i use

Comment: Without calling performSegue method how called prepareForSegue method?

Comment: i solved ,i am delete segue then in ButtonAction do it